# Kubernetes: when do i need to add /bin/sh -c to my command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-jobs

I am preparing for the CKAD exam and I am doing practice with the questions provide [here](https://github.com/dgkanatsios/CKAD-exercises/blob/master/c.pod_design.md)

I have a doubt over this two different way of executing commands. Here the example provided is with a job but I think the question might be more general and extendable to all containers.

Under the job exercises there are two requests:

[*Create a job named pi with image perl that runs the command with arguments "perl -Mbignum=bpi -wle 'print bpi(2000)'"*](https://github.com/dgkanatsios/CKAD-exercises/blob/master/c.pod_design.md#create-a-job-named-pi-with-image-perl-that-runs-the-command-with-arguments-perl--mbignumbpi--wle-print-bpi2000)

```
kubectl create job pi  --image=perl -- perl -Mbignum=bpi -wle 'print bpi(2000)'
```

[*Create a job with the image busybox that executes the command 'echo hello;sleep 30;echo world*](https://github.com/dgkanatsios/CKAD-exercises/blob/master/c.pod_design.md#create-a-job-with-the-image-busybox-that-executes-the-command-echo-hellosleep-30echo-world)

```
kubectl create job busybox --image=busybox -- /bin/sh -c 'echo hello;sleep 30;echo world'
```

Why in the second command I need to provide /bin/sh -c as well?

How could I understand when to use it and when not?

Comment: You are using `;` which isn't an argument to `echo` but a delimiter parsed by the shell, so you need a shell to parse and execute it. Otherwise, you'd be running `echo` with arguments `hello;sleep` and `30;echo` and `world` which is likely not what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, would you like to add it as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in first example

```
kubectl create job pi  --image=perl -- perl -Mbignum=bpi -wle 'print bpi(2000)'
```

you call a `perl` interpreter, `perl -Mbignum=bpi -wle 'print bpi(2000)'`

and in second example you call a bash shell command, `echo hello;sleep 30;echo world` therefore `/bin/sh -c`

```
kubectl create job busybox --image=busybox -- /bin/sh -c 'echo hello;sleep 30;echo world'
```

The `--` is saying after this it is a command is executed inside the container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wanted to ask you another thing if possible. If the command is something simpler like 'sleep 3600' do I need to provide '/bin/sh -c' before or just 'sleep 3600' in the command section (of course with right syntax ["sleep","3600"] would work fine?

Comment: You could look inside the container but I assume that `/bin/sh` will be just a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`. Example: `$ ls -l /bin/sh` `lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 4 Jun  1  2020 /bin/sh -> bash` `$ readlink -f /bin/sh` `/usr/bin/bash` So `/bin/sh` is really just an abstraction to your current shell. Beware it could also be `zsh` or `ash` etc. So if yo want that command will be executed with you currently configured shell, use `/bin/sh -c "<command>"`. If you executed only `sleep 3600` it is possible that in some containers shell is not configured at the `PATH` so it might end with error.